# Replacing project reference with NuGet packages on Azure DevOps

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget-package

We have Project Reference on the .net core library. During dotnet pack on VSTS we would like to change that Project Reference to the actual NuGet Package reference from VSTS Feed. 
Got nearly there using

```
dotnet remove ProjB.csproj reference ../../ProjA/src/ProjA.csproj 
dotnet add ProjB.csproj package ProjA --no-restore 
dotnet restore ProjB.csproj
dotnet pack ProjB.csproj --no-restore
```

Problem is in "dotnet add" with --no-restore as it adds reference with version="*":

```
<PackageReference Include="ProjA " Version="*" />
```

This causes referenced Package ProjA version in ProjB.nuspec to be incorrect (taken from the ProjA.scproj file instead of the actual version that was restored by "dotnet restore")

If not using --no-restore getting:

```
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://[our-team-project].pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/[our-feed]/nuget/v3/index.json.
error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

Question: is any way to add package with correct version (without using --no-restore) or forcing "dotnet pack" to output correct dependency version in ProjB.nuspec file?

Answer (score 0):

> is any way to add package with correct version (without using --no-restore) or forcing "dotnet pack" to output correct dependency version in ProjB.nuspec file?

You can try to add the option `[-v|--version]` to specify the actual version.

Check the document [dotnet add package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package) for some details.

**Synopsis**

```
dotnet add [<PROJECT>] package <PACKAGE_NAME> [-h|--help] [-f|--framework] [--interactive] [-n|--no-restore] [--package-directory] [-s|--source] [-v|--version]
```

As I test, it works fine:

[image]

**Note:** You should publish the package ProjA to your feed before execute the `dotnet restore` command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But that is the problem, that I don't know latest version of the ProjA...

Comment: @Algis, you can try to use the range formats `-v [1.0.0,2.0.0]`, check the ticket here:https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/10418